# Clarifications on proving lightlike vectors must be orthogonal with themselves

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, vectors, causality

I'm trying to prove that lightlike vectors in Minkowski space must be orthogonal to themselves, and I have two questions about this.

I tried two different approaches:

1. If lightlike, $ds^2=0$
   By definition of $ds$ in Minkowski space, we have $ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 - dt^2$ where I let c=1. 
   So, $ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 = dt^2$

but this means that $dt$ has to be zero, right? so the vectors would be something like 
$\begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\
    dx\\
dy\\
dz
  \end{pmatrix}$
but this doesn't seem right to me.

2. say that vectors are orthogonal if their scalar product is zero, meaning
   $g_{\mu \nu}A^{\mu}A^{\nu} = 0$
   for lightlike in Minkowski,
   $N_{\mu \nu}A^{\mu}A^{\nu} = 0$
   so, $A_{\nu}A^{\nu} = 0$
   but doesn't this just imply $A_{\nu}$ & $A^{\nu}$ must be orthogonal. These don't seem to be the same vector, so I'm not sure it's fair to conclude from this that a lightlike vector is orthogonal to itself.

So my questions are what is wrong with approach 1, and what conclusions can we make from approach 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We say two vectors $v,w$ are *orthogonal with respect to $g$* if $g(v,w)=0$. That's just by definition. In components, this is written as $g_{ab}v^aw^b=0$. If you're working in Minkowski with standard basis vectors, this is equivalent to $-(v^0w^0)+v^1w^1+v^2w^2+v^3w^3=0$.

Now, by definition a (non-zero) vector $v$ is said to be *lightlike* if $g(v,v)=0$, i.e as you wrote, $g_{ab}v^av^b=0$. Clearly, a lightlike vector $v$ is orthogonal (with respect to $g$) to itself according to these two definitions; there's nothing to be proven.

Now, recall the definition of the symbol $ds^2$, it means for any vector $v$, we define $ds^2(v)=g(v,v)$. So, saying a vector $v$ is lightlike is equivalent to saying $ds^2(v)=0$. Again, in Minkowski, if we write this out, this says
\begin{align}
0=ds^2(v)&=(-dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2)(v)\\
&=-[dt(v)]^2+[dx(v)]^2 + [dy(v)]^2+ [dz(v)]^2\\
&=-(v^0)^2+ (v^1)^2+(v^2)^2+(v^3)^2.
\end{align}
Which means the vector $v$ has components $(v^0,v^1,v^2,v^3)\in\Bbb{R}^4$ which lie on a certain cone (in the above, writing $dt(v)$ for instance means the $t$-component of the vector $v$, and $dx(v)$ means the $x$-component of the vector $v$ etc).

Where you went wrong in the first step is the final step

> ... So $ds^2= dx^2+dy^2+dz^2=dt^2$

No. As I've written above, it is $ds^2$ (when applied to $v$) which is $0$, and thus $dx^2+dy^2+dz^2=dt^2$ (everything applied on a given lightlike vector $v$). I'm not sure how you concluded $dt=0$ from here.

For example, in Minkowski, the vector $v=e_0+e_1= (1,1,0,0)$ is lightlike (among infinitely many other possible examples).

Comment: could you explain this line please? $(−^2+^2+^2+^2)()=−[()]^2+[()]^2+[()]^2+[()]^2$

Comment: @Relativisticcucumber $-dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$ is a quadratic form. It eats a vector $v$ and outputs a number. $(-dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2)(v)$ means the value of the quadratic form on the vector. This equals $-(dt^2)(v)+ (dx^2)(v)+(dy^2)(v)+(dz^2)(v)$. And the meaning of these symbols is for example $(dx)^2(v):= (dx\otimes dx)(v,v)=(dx(v))\cdot (dx(v))= [dx(v)]^2$. So really it's a matter of unwinding definitions.

Comment: But, having said this, note that writing $(-dt^2+dz^2+dy^2+dz^2)(v)$ is just a different notation for writing $g(v,v)$.